# Htaccess rewrite to file located up one level

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess in a subdomain with the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^feed([0-9]+)$ ../image.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So basically I want to redirect requests from `feed` which is located in a subdomain to `image.php` file which is located in the main domain (just one directory above). Using `../` doesn't seem to work like in PHP.

So how can I rewrite to file in the parent directory?

Thanks!

Comment: I imagine Apache is deliberately not letting you navigate out of the web root of your subdomain - try using the URL of the parent site instead of ../

Comment: Using the URL will actually redirect to the other domain.

Comment: Ah ok so you want the request to remain within the domain - why not just `require` your `image.php` file in a new file on your subdomain? That way the rewrite shouldn't giv you any trouble.

Comment: I know that but isn't there a solution via htaccess instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_alias` for this. Add the following directive to .htaccess file of subdomain:

```
AliasMatch "^/feed([0-9]+)$" "/absolute/path/to/image.php?id=$1"
```

Alternatively you can use symbolic links, but in my opinion [AliasMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch) directive is better.